# Complete Binary Tree swapping child and parent bug

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, binary-tree, swap

I'm doing a project for school and I have a weird bug.
I'm implementing a Complete Binary Tree and I have trouble with the swapping of a node with his parent.

During my testing I found 1 case is not working properly.

This :
[image: Broken case]

All of the other swap work fine except in that case

The structure of my tree is as such

```
typedef struct TreeNode {
    void * data;
    struct TreeNode * left;
    struct TreeNode * right;
    struct TreeNode * parent;
} TNode;

typedef struct CompleteBinaryTree {
    TNode * root;
    TNode * last;
    int numelm;
} CBTree;

CBTree * newCBTree(void)
{
    CBTree * ret = malloc(sizeof(CBTree));

    if( ret )
    {
        ret->root = NULL;
        ret->last = NULL;

        ret->numelm = 0;
    }
}

TNode * newTNode( void * data )
{
    TNode *ret = malloc(sizeof(TNode));
    if( ret )
    {
        ret->data = data;
        ret->parent = ret->left = ret->right = NULL;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This is my swapping function :

```
void CBTreeSwap(CBTree* tree, TNode* parent, TNode* child)
{
  assert(parent != NULL && child != NULL && (child == parent->left || child == parent->right));

  if (child == tree->last)
    tree->last = parent;

  if(child == parent->left)
  {        
    if(child->left != NULL)
      child->left->parent = parent;

    parent->left = child->left;
    child->left = parent;

    if (child->right != NULL)
      child->right->parent = parent;

    if (parent->right != NULL)
      parent->right->parent = child;

    TNode * tmp = child->right;
    child->right = parent->right;
    parent->right = tmp;

    if (parent != tree->root)
    {
      parent->parent->left = child;
      child->parent = parent->parent;
      parent->parent = child;
    }
    else
    {
      child->parent = NULL;
      tree->root = child;
      parent->parent = child;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if(child->right != NULL)
      child->right->parent = parent;

    parent->right = child->right;
    child->right = parent;

    if(child->left != NULL)
      child->left->parent = parent;

    if(parent->left != NULL)
      parent->left->parent = child;

    TNode * tmp = child->left;
    child->left = parent->left;
    parent->left = tmp;

    if(parent != tree->root)
    {
      parent->parent->right = child;
      child->parent = parent->parent;
      parent->parent = child;
    }
    else
    {
      child->parent = NULL;
      tree->root = child;
      parent->parent = child;
    }
  }
}
```

To insert in the tree in use this :

```
void CBTreeInsert(CBTree* tree, void* data)
{
  TNode * tmp = newTNode(data);
  TNode * curr = tree->last;

  if(tree->root == NULL)
  { //empty
    tree->root = tmp;
  }
  else if(tree->last == tree->root)
  { //one node
    tree->last->left = tmp;
    tmp->parent = tree->root;
  }
  else if(tree->last->parent->right == NULL)
  { //general
    tree->last->parent->right = tmp;
    tmp->parent = tree->last->parent;
  }
  else if (tree->last == tree->last->parent->right)
  { //degenarated
    curr = tree->last->parent ;

    while (1)
    {
      if (curr == tree->root)
        break ;

      if (curr == curr->parent->left)
      {
        curr = curr->parent->right ;
        assert(curr != NULL) ;
        break ;
      }
      curr = curr->parent ;
   }

   while (curr->left != NULL) 
   {
      assert(curr->right != NULL) ;
      curr = curr->left ;
   }
    assert(curr->right == NULL) ;
    tmp->parent = curr ;
    curr->left  = tree->last = tmp;
  }
  else 
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error\n");
  }
  tree->last = tmp;
  tree->numelm++;
}
```

So I build my test like this :

```
void main(){
  int * i[15], j;

  CBTree * tree  = newCBTree(); //create tree

  for(j=0; j<15; j++)
  {
    i[j] = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(i[j]) = j+1;

    CBTreeInsert(tree, (int*) i[j]);
  }

    //All these work
    CBTreeSwap(T, T->root->left, T->root->left->left);
    CBTreeSwap(T, T->root, T->root->left);
    CBTreeSwap(T, T->root->right, T->root->right->right);
    CBTreeSwap(T, T->root, T->root->right);
    CBTreeSwap(T, T->last->parent, T->last);

    //This one is broken
    CBTreeSwap(T, T->root->left, T->root->left->right);
}
```

When I run that broken test and try to view my tree I get all the branches of my tree followed by a seg fault.

This is just a part of a bigger project if you need more of my code don't hesitate to ask

Thank you !

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem generates a tree corruption not only when `T->left` and `T->left->right` are swapped (corrupting all `T->left` subtree left) but also when `T->right` and `T->right->left` are swapped.

The problem resides somewhere in `CBTreeSwap()` function.

Its implementation is actually tricky. It's not easy to understand it, so I'll propose my implementation. I can just say that the root of the problem is probably that somewhere, in the swapping process, you assign some fields of `parent`/`child` without paying attention to the fact that they are already changed!

---

### The fix

Please find below the corrected version of `CBTreeSwap()`. It is correct the distinction between the case in which child is either `parent->left` or `parent->right`, but many other actions are common in these two cases. The code is commented.

```
void CBTreeSwap(CBTree* tree, TNode* parent, TNode* child)
{
    assert(parent != NULL && child != NULL && (child == parent->left || child == parent->right));

    if (child == tree->last)
        tree->last = parent;

    /* Save child's childs */
    TNode *tmpL = child->left, *tmpR = child->right;

    /* Link child (new parent!) to parent's parent */
    if(parent != tree->root)
    {
        TNode *parpar = parent->parent;
        child->parent = parpar;

        /* Is parent left or right child of his parent? */
        if( parent->parent->left == parent)
          parpar->left = child;
        else
          parpar->right = child;
    }
    else
    {
        child->parent = NULL;
        tree->root = child;
    }

    /* In order to actually swap nodes we need to know if child is at parent's left or right*/       
    if(child == parent->left)
    {        
        /* Link parent's other child to child */
        parent->right->parent  = child;
        child->right  = parent->right;

        /* Link former parent to child's right (making it its new right child) */
        child->left = parent;
        parent->parent = child;
    }
    else /* child == parent->right */
    {
        /* Link parent's other child to child */
        parent->left->parent  = child;
        child->left  = parent->left;

        /* Link former parent to child's right (making it its new right child) */
        child->right = parent;
        parent->parent = child;
    }

    /* Link child's childs to former parent */
    parent->left  = tmpL;
    parent->right = tmpR;
    if(tmpL != NULL)
        tmpL->parent = parent;
    if(tmpR != NULL)
        tmpR->parent = parent;
}
```

So:

1. Save `child`'s childs.
2. Link the child (new parent) to old parent's parent, managing the case in which `parent` is the root node. We need to understand if `parent` is either at the left or at the right of his parent.
3. Swap `parent` and `child` according to their original mutual position. If we get wrong, we might corrupt a whole subtree.
4. Restore `child`'s childs

**I tested the code above and it worked as expected.**

---

**PS**: though it is unrelated to this question, consider using an array and a loop for the initialization. The code below behaves like your initialization. Isn't it more elegant?

```
  int * i[15], j;

  CBTree * tree  = newCBTree(); //create tree

  for(j=0; j<15; j++)
  {
    i[j] = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(i[j]) = j+1;

    CBTreeInsert(tree, (int*) i[j]);
  }
```

---

### An alternative solution

But there's an easier solution to achieve your specific goal: **why swapping entire subtrees when, at the end of the program, just nodes *contents* need to be swapped?**

So your swap function becomes:

```
void CBTreeSwap(CBTree* tree, TNode* parent, TNode* child)
{
    assert(parent != NULL && child != NULL && (child == parent->left || child == parent->right));

    void *tmpData = parent->data;
    parent->data = child->data;
    child->data = tmpData;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
My teacher told me that my fonction CBTreeSwap() was fine and that's why I was looking elsewhere.
I know that moving the data is the easy solution but it's not the point of the exercice unfortunately.
I'll keep poking at it.

Comment: @Crunchy I confirm that the problem was `CBTreeSwap()`. I edited my answer providing also the solution in the form you asked form. I explained every step. Feel free to accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: This is perfect ! I have a better understanding of what I did wrong now. I will use your version for my final project and will link your answer to my teacher. For the initialization I will update the post but I don't need to be elegant it's just a brute way for my testing but thank you anyway !